# How to use a backend keras function in a definition of a custom serving signature?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I have an issue with defining a custom signature, because it tries to call `.numpy()` and produces this error: `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'`

Here is a `tf.function()` wrapper of it:

```
@tf.function(input_signature=[tf.TensorSpec([None, 27], dtype=tf.float32, name='inputs')])
def predict_output(x):
    func_p = K.function([model.get_layer('input_f').input], model.get_layer('probs').output)
    proba = func_p(x)
    return {'scores': proba}
```

And then saving the model `model.save("saved_model", signatures={"serving_default": predict_output})` fails.

The `func_p` takes a part of the model that simply creates a bunch of dense layers and then concatenates them in a certain way. There is no numpy usage anywhere in the code. But from what I understand this might be related to the fact that the `keras.backend` functions return a `numpy` array? Is there any other way to define this signature? The func_p works by itself if I give it an array it produces what I need, I just can't save the model.